# Asymmetric key encryption for securing SOAP webservice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, linux, encryption-asymmetric

I'd like to authenticate the caller of my SOAP webservice (deployed in Ruby 1.8.7/Rails 2.3.5using datanoise gem in Red Hat enterprise linux 5) using some encrypted tag in the XML requests. Normally the client is a windows program (maybe C#/.Net windows programs - not Java/Ruby) which should generate a varying encrypted key in each call to the webservice based on a key/salt - while my server side would always be able to decode it with the private key. Knowledge of the encrypted token on the wire should not allow a third-party program to simply replicate the fully encrypted token and access the webservice. I am looking into OpenSSL but am a newbie to cryptography. The string being encrypted for identification could be (among other items) the MAC ID of the trusted client, which when decrypted would match the stored value on the server side of the trusted hosts.

I've found lots of possibilities on the Ruby side, but need to ideally ensure that the solution does not impose (or minimizes) any library or installation requirement on the windows client side. What i'm most struggling with is a way to generate a new key each time the call is made, so that anyone sniffing the traffic cannot simply infer the mode to create the encrypted tag by getting access to the key.

Comment: Someone here may be able to provide you with an answer but my experience to date is that with security, if you don't have an in-depth knowledge, you should never implement it yourself. Doing it well isn't easy. I'd strongly recommend you find a standard encryption system with libraries for all relevant platforms and use that

Comment: Is there a simpler/more appropriate solution in implementing using certificates? I will have 100's of client programs who should be individually authorized and authenticated - while protecting against a rogue webservice client wanting to access the service by snooping the traffic or having access to generated encrypted tags as text.

Comment: It depends how much control you have over the target machines. If you can add Trusted Root Authorities and make yourself a trusted root, you can auto-generate certificates relatively easily ([A .Net example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163454.aspx)). If not, the honest answer is I don't know enough to advise you and wouldn't want to mislead you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are authenticating the caller here and not necessarily just the contents of what they send, there's no need to put the authentication mechanism into the SOAP request. Others have tried to do what you are after with [WS-Security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Security), so if at all, I'd go with that.

There have been problems with the security of the scheme, though, but probably the biggest deal breaker is that there's no support for it available in Ruby (that I know of at least, please correct me if I'm wrong!).

Probably the easiest way to achieve client authentication on both ends would be using mutually authenticated TLS (the former SSL). This will ensure authentication on the transport level, which should suffice in your case. Actual authentication will then happen by first checking the validity of the certificate that is sent by the client (Ruby OpenSSL takes care of that for you), and once that is established, you check it against a white list of known certificates that you maintain on your server.

Please don't invent your own scheme, cryptographic protocols are among the hardest things to get right (that's why there are problems with WS-Security), TLS is probably as good as it gets right now and it has broad support in any language.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to get back to this - TLS/SSL is what I finally ended up with (didn't see your answer - but you were right on!)